# Bluetooth audio hijacking from Chrome

Tags: sound, bluetooth, google-chrome, 22.10, pipewire

I have Ubuntu 22.10 and Google Chrome 108.0.5359.98. Ever since I installed 22.10 (I was previously at 18.04 LTS), I have been experiencing this maddening issue with my bluetooth headset. I have paired my Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra to my Bose QC35 II. I have also paired the headset with my Dell XPS 15 (9520 from 2022). If I'm listening music from Youtube in a tab and somebody calls me, it switches to the phone which is great, but then, if I click on a tab in Chrome, the sound is hijacked by Chrome and I can no longer hear the audio from the phone. The tab might not have any audio in it at all. This "hijacking" typically goes away in 10-15 secs and it switches back to the phone, but you've missed part of the conversation. This used work just fine and I also used to have at least one more device paired up (usually, my tablet). It's really annoying and I can't find how to sort this out.

Also, the quality of the sound is just not as good as it used to be. I'm a bit of audiophile and I can hear this very faint distorted noise somewhere at the back when music is playing in the headphones in Youtube (in Chrome). If I open the same Youtube video on my phone with the same headset, the sound is flawless.

I am not sure if this is a pipewire, or a Chrome issue, or perhaps an issue with the underlying bluetooth libraries.

Any ideas will be welcome!